# code is coming in catch block even if no exception is thrown

Tags: java

I am tyring to ensure thta contents from the url are successfully written to file. For this i am using following code

```
public void copyFileFromUrl(URL source, File target, int count) throws IOException {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;

    if (target != null) {
        try {       
            if (!target.exists()) {
                target.createNewFile();
                log.debug("target file created for " + target);
                log.debug("downloading source .... " + source);

                if (source == null) {                   
                    log.debug("Null source .... " + ScormFileWriter.class.getName());
                    return;         
                } else {    
                    in = source.openStream();   
                }   
                out = new FileOutputStream(target);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }

                log.debug("The contents from the URL: " + source + " are successfully written to the file " + target);

            } else {
                log.debug("skipping creation of asset");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            if(count < 3){
                log.debug("trouble with " + target);
                if (in != null) {       
                    in.close(); 
                }
                if (out != null) {  
                     out.close();   
                }

                // Attempt to delete it
                boolean success = target.delete();

                if (!success) { 
                    log.debug("Unable to delete " + target);    
                } else {
                    copyFileFromUrl(source, target, ++count);   
                }               
            }

            log.debug("trouble in downloading source after trying " + count +  " times: " + source);
            e.printStackTrace();        
        } finally {         
            if (in != null) {               
                in.close();             
            }           
            if (out != null) {              
                 out.close();               
            }             
        }       
    }   
}
```

Now what is happening that suppose on first calling when function comes to

```
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
```

I unplug my cable, the exception is thrown and code comes to catch block and call the function again. Now i plug in the cable, this time `while` loops complete and the line

```
log.debug("The contents from the URL: " + source + " are successfully written to the file " + target);
```

prints, code comes to finally block and then code comes to these two lines

```
log.debug("trouble in downloading source after trying " + count +  " times: " + source);
e.printStackTrace();
```

Why? This time no exception is thrown, everything works fine, Why code comes to catch block? This time after finally code should return to normal?

Thanks

Comment: does `e.printStackTrace();` print something?

Comment: try to print Exception class, you will know whether exception is thrown (e.getClass().getName())

Comment: I would use a mock object to simulate the behaviour you are trying to have with your cable (un-)plugging. You can be sure that, if you enter a `catch` block, an exception was thrown in the `try` block. The connection is not back, immediately when the cable is back in, the OS has to do some work first...

Comment: yes unknown host exception.... Is this happening because of recursion ?

Comment: Shouldn't the repeat part be in the finally section?

Comment: @RST actually the finally section i think is for the final thing. I mean when everything is ok, then come to finally for cleaning. Its purely my thinking :). That's why i didn't call the repeat part in the finally. But if this is a performance issue then tell me i will definitely put the repeat part in the finally :)

Comment: I was assuming if no error occurs, the catch exeption part is not used. In the finally your first run is done so you can start the next one. But I could be wrong about the concept of try/catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are recursively calling the method. The first time the exception is thrown, the code forks to go and call itself again, the printing line is not reached until the execution thread comes back from this second call to the method. Once the method completes properly, the execution returns to the first "instance" of the method and execution falls through to the printing line. I think a better approach is to loop through the attempt to get the file instead of recursively calling the same method. If you must call it recursively, make sure that the methods does all it needs to do, execution wise, before calling itself again.

**EDIT**
You can always move the printing lines to just before the recursive call so the method would have nothing to do when the execution comes back to it except to "unroll" the recursive calls. If you want to avoid the recursive calls I was thinking along the lines of letting the loop go on for a maximum of 3 times but if successful you exit the loop, otherwise, just let the loop go back to top. something along the lines of:

```
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;

if (target != null) {
  while(n<3){
    try {       
        if (!target.exists()) {
            target.createNewFile();
            log.debug("target file created for " + target);
            log.debug("downloading source .... " + source);

            if (source == null) {                   
                log.debug("Null source .... " + ScormFileWriter.class.getName());
                return;         
            } else {    
                in = source.openStream();   
            }   
            out = new FileOutputStream(target);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            log.debug("The contents from the URL: " + source + " are successfully written to the file " + target);

        } else {
            log.debug("skipping creation of asset");
        }
        n=4; or break;
    } catch (Exception e) {


            log.debug("trouble with " + target);
            if (in != null) {       
                in.close(); 
            }
            if (out != null) {  
                 out.close();   
            }

            // Attempt to delete it
            boolean success = target.delete();

            if (!success) { 
                log.debug("Unable to delete " + target);

            } else {
               // copyFileFromUrl(source, target, ++count);
            }               

           n++;
         if(n == 2){
            log.debug("trouble in downloading source after trying " + count +  " times: " +           source);
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
    } finally {         
        if (in != null) {               
            in.close();             
        }           
        if (out != null) {              
             out.close();               
        }             
    }       
  }
```

Of course you may need to adjust for logging and exit conditions to meet your specific needs

Comment: Actually i am trying for three times, that's why i am using recursion. Because if i try to again write in the `if (count < 3)` then what will happen if again exception is thrown between writing. I am already in catch block ?